# How to Enable the new LogBox (RN)

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to enable the new LogBox in React Native (v0.62.0-rc.2), I just have to add a line to the "index.js" file but it doesn't work.

> RC2 introduces the new LogBox experience behind a feature flag. To try
>   it out, add the following to your index.js file:

```
require('react-native').unstable_enableLogBox()
```

index.js

```
require('react-native').unstable_enableLogBox();

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Error output:

```
TypeError: _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[1], "react-native").unstable_enableLogBox is not a function.
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, maybe it's not the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to do the following:

1. create a file in the project root title it `intro.js`
2. add `require('react-native').unstable_enableLogBox();` to intro.js
3. add `import './intro';` at the top of index.js

This worked with me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it. For some reason imports get resolved super early, which seems to cause the following error:

> Error: LogBox must be enabled before AppContainer is required so that it can properly wrap the console methods.
>
> Please enable LogBox earlier in your app.

Move the contents of your entrypoint (usually `index.js`) to another file (`_index.js` for example), then `require()` it from your entrypoint AFTER enabling the logbox:

```
if(__DEV__)
  require('react-native').unstable_enableLogBox();

require('./_index');
```

Answer (score 0):

import {name as appName} from './app.json';
require('react-native').unstable_enableLogBox();

please write in simple manner I mentioned above please check screen shot for Log box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, identify where is the main file of your entire app. For example, if you are using a file like [Reactotron](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/blob/master/docs/quick-start-react-native.md) config file you will put this line before all imports:

```
require('react-native').unstable_enableLogBox();
```

Therefore, if you are not using something like Reactotron you will put the above line, before your App import on index.js in the root of project, like this:

```
require('react-native').unstable_enableLogBox();
...
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import { name } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(name, () => App);
```

I hope i've helped! =)

Comment: This caused the following error on my side : "LogBox must be enabled before AppContainer is required so that it can properly wrap the console methods.". See my answer for a possible fix

Answer (score 0):

According to the React Native [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#logbox) this is how you would implement it:

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

// Ignore log notification by message:
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Warning: ...']);

// Ignore all log notifications:
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();
```

I did this at the very top of `App.js` and it worked great.